# caml query on lists connected by lookup columns

Tags: list, caml-query

I want to use CAML to query two lists that are connected by a lookup column. If I set the lookup column in List 1 to connect to the Title column of List 2, can I do a CAML query that joins them? Or do I have to connect the lookup column in List 1 to the ID column of List 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can perform CAML query join even if you don't connect to ID. However, in the CAML `Join` property, the `RefType` will still remain "Id" and not Title.